# Return post tags with description

Tags: tags, description

I've got a shortcode working to return tags that are used on a particular post but can't figure out how to return the description with it.

```
function returnpost_tags(){
       return get_the_tag_list('',', ',' ');
   }
add_shortcode('post-tags', 'returnpost_tags');
```

I tried

```
return get_the_tag_list('',', ',' $description');
```

but obviously something not right

as a bonus I'd like to alternatively as a separate function return the list with description but without the links to the tags archive which is the normal behavior

thanks for the help

Comment: This question is already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499308/loop-to-display-taxonomy-terms-and-description, 
I think you can't use **get_the_tag_list()**, you have to try with **get_terms()** .

Comment: thanks @Ronald but I can't even begin to decipher how that thread would address this - it looks like completely different scenario

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can loop with custom taxonomy.

```
function returnpost_tags(){
// get tags by post ID 
$post_ID = get_the_ID();
// here, you can add any custom tag
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_ID , 'post_tag' ); 
echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

// The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
$term_link = get_term_link( $term );
$term_ID = $term->term_id;
// If there was an error, continue to the next term.
if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
    continue;
}

echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
echo term_description($term_ID);

   // another option
   // echo  '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';

}

echo '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('post-tags', 'returnpost_tags');
```

You can replace **post_tag** with your custom taxonomy

```
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag' );
```

To get tag's description, you can use one of the below method.

```
 echo $term->description;
```

or

```
 echo term_description($term->term_id);
```

Comment: Hi @Ronald - the output works well, however it is getting ALL the tags and not just the tags associated with the specific post. I tried a couple alternatives for $terms = get_terms( 'post_tag' );  but just don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: I thought you want to print out all the tags. 
To get the tags which are associated with the specific post, you need to add the **post ID**. It would be like this **$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'post_tag' );** . I've updated my answer with new codes and hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks @Ronald, just what I was hoping for - it was the piece about         // get tags by post ID 
$post_ID = get_the_ID();   that was the missing element for me.  BTW I'm getting PHP error warnings associated with ** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ** -- which reading about elsewhere apparently has something to do with needing an array --- but I can't quite figure out how to change that....  there is a waterfall effect with this error -- meaning about 10 other pieces connected to each other about what gets displayed are flagged as invalid, so not exactly trivial I don't think.

Comment: ** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ** --- I can't seem to figure out how to use an array for this, any ideas

Comment: FYI - I was getting display problems because the term definitions were appearing at the top of the post no matter what I did with html, however making this change   combining ECHO and RETURN - solved the issue 
 echo '<div class="absolute"><p style="margin:0;"><strong>' . $term->name . '</strong></p></div>';
  return term_description( $term->term_id, 'post_tag' );

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to work with the tags, you can use [`get_the_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) in the loop instead:

```
function my_tag_shortcode(){
    // Get a list of tags
    $tags = get_the_tags();
    $data ='';
    // Run a loop to output the data
    foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
        $data .= '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'. $tag->name .'</a><span>'. $tag->description .'</span>';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now, you have the tag's name, ID, description, and more. Choose whatever you want, based on your needs.

Comment: thank @Jack Johansson --     'return $data' needs to be    'return $data;' but it wprked returning what I need